# Angular - Delete data from a restfull webservice using observables

Tags: javascript, angular, web-services, typescript

I'd like to delete data from a restfull webservice with angular. I was using the method which is provided on the angular tutorial site:

```
delete(id: number): Promise<void> {
    const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.delete(url, {headers: this.headers})
    .toPromise()
    .then(() => null)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

It is working but I'd like to do the same using observables instead of promises. I've tried this but it is not working:

```
delete(id: number) {
    const url = '${this.heroesUrl}/${id}';
    return this.http.delete(url).map(
        response => {},
        error => console.log(error)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that is because **Observables are lazy**. Your call won't be made until you `.subscribe()` to it.

Comment: The correct term is 'cold observable' - as opposed to 'hot'. You can't blame someone for being lazy if he/she is cold meat...

Answer (score 0):

Have you subscribed to the observable?